# FileOpenPicker - how to specify Custom Start Path

Tags: c#, uwp

can you tell me how to specify custom start path in file open picker class??

'openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation' does not shown custom path option.

thank you for reading!

```
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xml");            

        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();


        if(file!=null)
        {                
            var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

        }
        else
        {
            //
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot specify a custom start path for that. You can only use the path which are mentioned over there. You can read about it [over here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.pickerlocationid)

Comment: Thank you for replying! however, Is there no another File Dialog Solution for UWP?

Comment: As far as my knowledge, no there isn't.